# Scraping dynamic HTML content with YQL

Tags: javascript, html, yql

I'm trying to scrape the content from this [page](http://eju.tv) with YQL.  The problem I run into is that the source code only shows the first 4 articles (starting at the < main class="content"> tag). Once you scroll down the page the other articles start showing up as does the source code.  Is there a way to scrape the page without having to scroll down?  I did notice they have a hidden rss feed but I really need more than the 10 items given in there.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's because they are fetching the other articles with javascript. I didn't even visit the site and I know that. So you'll need to fetch those articles with AJAX from YQL (I have no experience in YQL so)

Comment: @EasyBB Ok ... thanks I guess.

Comment: Use the developer tools to figure out how the javascript is getting the content from the server.

Comment: I only lead, i let others figure out the rest themselves. So you know two things, one that you're not getting all the articles because they are dynamic and two you need ajax to fetch more articles.

Comment: @user104317  Thanks!  I was able to figure out how the content was being loaded.